# Geographical Heatmap with state-level granularity in python

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, geocoding, heatmap

I'm follow the tutorial [here](https://eatsleepdata.com/data-viz/how-to-generate-a-geographical-heatmap-with-python.html) and able to generate heatmap based on geocode. But I want is the heatmap color the map based on state of the country instead of geocode (Heatmap that based on the state boundary). The sample image like [this](http://imagenesde.co/mapping-heat-map-python-of-us-heatmap-2/mapping-heat-map-python-of-us-heatmap-2-inspirationa-mapping-heat-map-python-us-figmapd-best-bridgeforworld-us/). Does any python library was able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just the information for those who search for this. [Here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/292-choropleth-map-with-folium/) have the tutorial about this. But you need to search the geojson file for your own country.